# Función GetTimeFormat en C++

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++, visual-c++, c++98

Buenas.

Quiero mostrar por pantalla la fecha y hora actual y tengo que utilizar la función, getTimeFormat() para hacerlo.

Yo lo tengo así:

```
int main(int arg, char *argv[]) {

SYSTEMTIME today;
TCHAR pszDate[200];

GetTimeFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, TIME_FORCE24HOURFORMAT, &today, NULL, pszDate, 200);
printf("La hora es: %d: %d: %d\n", today.wHour, today.wMinute, today.wSecond);

return 0;
}
```

Y al ejecutar este programa se me muestra en la consola el siguiente mensaje:

La hora es: 52428: 52428: 52428

Algo falla, pero no sé que puede ser, espero que puedan echarme una mano.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

citando tu codigo, no especificas bien la variable `today`

```
printf("La hora es: %d: %d: %d\n", today.wHour, today.wMinute, today.wSecond);
```

segun ref:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194815.aspx
hay varios parametros,

> h Hours without leading zeros (12-hour clock)
>
> hh Hours with leading zeros (12-hour clock)
>
> H Hours without leading zeros (24-hour clock)
>
> HH Hours with leading zeros (24-hour clock)
>
> m Minutes without leading zeros
>
> mm Minutes with leading zeros
>
> s Seconds without leading zeros

cambia algo asi:

```
SYSTEMTIME stBuf;
CString    strD;
CString    strT;
CString    strData;

GetDateFormat( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DATE_LONGDATE, &stBuf, NULL, strD.GetBuffer(), strD.GetLength() );
strT = _T("HH':'mm':'ss");
GetTimeFormat( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, TIME_FORCE24HOURFORMAT, &stBuf, NULL, strT.GetBuffer(), strT.GetLength() );
strData.Format( _T("%s, %s"), strD, strT );
```

Comment: Es que si lo pongo así me sale en rojo "CString" y he añadido #include <cstring> o #include <string.h> , pero me sale eso en rojo y no puedo ejecutar. Y el FileTimeToSystemTime( &m_pK1->m_ftMyData, &stBuf ) me da error porque no esta la variable m_pK1 , ¿que tipo de variable es?

Comment: @DanielRuiz edite mi respuesta, solo con la parte que te sirve

Comment: @DanielRuiz si te sirvio mi respuesta no olvides dar bien !!!

Comment: Me sigue dando error y no sé que probar más. Además he cambiado CString a TCHAR porque no me lo reconoce.

Comment: @DanielRuiz si usas string? en ves de CString

Comment: Me sale en rojo string, al ponerme encima me dice: el identificador "string" no está definido. Es que yo estoy utilizando Visual Studio 2015.